# Determining dz/dx value from Triangle 3D Vertices

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I have 3D Vertices of a triangle as (x1,y1,z1) ; (x2,y2,z2) and (x3,y3,z3).
I would like to know the value of dz/dx.

I have been looking into various 3D Geometry forums,but could not find relevant things.I am trying to write the algorithm in C++.

I would be really glad,if someone can help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is `z = f(x)` for which you want `dz/dx`?

Comment: Probably a question better asked at https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: My guess is `(z2-z1)/(x2-x1)` if `x1!=x2` otherwise use different two points from the triangle. This will give you the `z` change relative to `x` axis (derivation of `z` by `x`). But as you did not define what you mean by `dz/dx` even what is `dz,dx` is this unclear (and most likely not programming related) so +Close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general plane equation is:

```
a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are floating numbers. So, at first you need to find these numbers. Note, however, that you can set the `d = 0`, because all planes with the same `a, b, c` coefficients and different `d` are parallel to each other. So, you get a system of linear equations:

```
a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 = 0
a*x2 + b*y2 + c*z2 = 0
a*x3 + b*y3 + c*z3 = 0
```

After you solve the system you'll have these three coefficients - then you can express `z` as a function of `x` and `y`:

```
z = - (a*x + b*y) / c
```

Then it'll be easy to find the `dz/dx`:

```
dz/dx = - a / c
```

There are some special cases, which you'll need to care of in your code - for example, what if all your points are collinear, or you got `c = 0`. You'll need to be very careful to cover ALL the corner cases.